# How to loop through all terminal windows, stop any running processes, and close window if the window is not named a certain string?

Tags: applescript

I have a terminal window called "myTerminalWindow", and I wan't to be able to close all other terminal windows not named "myTerminalWindow". Other windows may be running a process so we'd have to stop the process before closing the window. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way that should work regardless of how the preferences for closing the Terminal windows are configured:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set theWindows to windows
    repeat with aWindow in theWindows
        if (name of aWindow) contains "myTerminalWindow" then
            display dialog ("Will not close " & name of aWindow)
        else
            set theProcesses to processes of aWindow
            set clean commands of current settings of aWindow to theProcesses
            close aWindow without saving
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

By updating the "clean commands" property with the list of currently running processes you tell Terminal it's OK to kill the processes without prompting.

If you want a more sophisticated way of ending running processes then you might iterate through the list of running processes and close them down in whatever way you find appropriate. Terminal's "do script" command would be useful for this.